# Library instance has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, appium, robotframework

Cannot get over last step here when trying to work around issues in `AppiumLibrary`(Swipe, Tap do not work in RF).

I had to a create python library as advised but having this error:

```
 AttributeError: AppiumTests instance has no attribute 'id'
```

the line with error is this:

```
action.tap(x, y, count).perform()
```

here is the python lib code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from AppiumLibrary import AppiumLibrary
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction

class AppiumTests():

    def set_up():
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '5.1.1'
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'NNNNNN'
        desired_caps['app'] = 'NNNNN'
        desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'NNNNNN'
        url = str("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub")
        driver = webdriver.Remote(url, desired_caps)

    def tear_down(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def tap_loc(x, y, count=1):
        driver = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('AppiumLibrary')._current_application()
        action = TouchAction(driver)
        action.tap(x, y, count).perform()

    def get_driver(self):
        return self._current_application()
```

Comment: So, define self.id = "something" in set_up()?

Comment: Your `get_driver` also has the problem that it's returning `self._current_application()` but your class doesn't have that either. Also, `tear_down` tries to access `self.driver` but you haven't defined that, either.  It almost looks like you think you've inherited from something, but haven't.

Comment: thanks guys! resolved by getting rid of set_up() function and adding this to tap_loc() function: 'action.tap(x=x, y=y, count=count).perform()'. This helped to avoid that AttributeError: AppiumTests instance has no attribute 'id'